# How should i call viewpager instance in activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My ViewPager is located in nested fragment, because i also have navigation drawer. My question is how can i call instance of viewpager in MainActivity.java, so i can set current item of viewpager using method `setCurrentItem()` from MainActivity.java in method `onBackPressed()`, when for example user is on third fragment of viewpager and when he presses back button he should be returned on first fragment.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to declare RecyclerView as public. Not sure if it has to be static, but it'll tell you if it has to.

Second, you need to call an instance of the fragment that holds the RecyclerView.
For example, `Fragment recyclerFrag = new RecyclerFrag();`

After that, try calling your RecyclerView from that instance and use `setCurrentItem()`. For example, `recyclerFrag.recyclerView.setCurrentItem(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. You should first create one method in FragmentActivity where is initialized your `ViewPager` and set return type `ViewPager`. Something like this:

```
public ViewPager getViewPager() {
    return mViewPager; // instance of view pager
}
```

After that create object of your Fragment in Activity where you are calling instance of view pager like this:

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
```

And in my case i should call viewpager in `onBackPressed()`:

```
HomeFragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
            if (fragment1.getViewPager().getCurrentItem() == 1 || fragment1.getViewPager().getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                fragment1.getViewPager().setCurrentItem(0);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
```